# Square root of a matrix with complex elements

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex

How to compute the square root of the matrix

```
Rho = {{Wxx, Wxy, Wxz}, {Wyx, Wyy, Wyz}, {Wzx, Wzy, Wzz}}
```

if not all of its elements are real?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all matrices have a square root matrix, but you can try:

```
Rho = {{Wxx, Wxy, Wxz}, {Wyx, Wyy, Wyz}, {Wzx, Wzy, Wzz}};
MatrixPower[Rho, 1/2]
```

You can achieve the same result through diagonalization of `Rho` into $V\Lambda V^{-1}$ then taking the square root of the eigenvalues to give $V\Lambda^{1/2} V^{-1}$:

```
val = Eigenvalues[Rho];
vec = Eigenvectors[Rho]; (* each vec needs to be a column so use transpose *)
Transpose[vec].Sqrt[DiagonalMatrix[val]].Inverse[Transpose[vec]]
```

Comment: `Simplify` will shorten this considerably.

Comment: @flinty Can you please explain this sentence "then taking the square root of the eigenvalues to give..."?

Comment: You put your eigenvalues in a diagonal matrix $$\Lambda=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda _3 \\
\end{array}\right)$$ Then raise that matrix to the power 1/2. It's diagonal, so you just have $$\Lambda^{1/2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\sqrt{\lambda _1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{\lambda_2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\lambda _3} \\ \end{array}\right) $$

Comment: This of course assumes the starting matrix is not *defective*. Otherwise, you would need to use the Jordan form instead of the eigendecomposition.

Comment: Relevant MathematicsSE answer for taking the power if you have the Jordan form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910635/power-of-a-matrix-given-its-jordan-form